# How to get delay of 30 sec in current time in php?

Tags: php, datetime, date

Date("F d Y H:i:s") gives current time in php. How can I get delay of 30 secs and 1 min in current time using php, not sure but something like Date ("F d Y H:i:s-30") or Date("F d Y H:i-1:s") ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
date("F d Y H:i:s", time() + 90)
```

`date` has a second, optional parameter:  the timestamp to convert to a string.  `time` returns the current timestamp, which is just an integer, so you can add 90 to it to get the time 90 seconds from the current time.

Answer (score 3):

You mean format the time for 1:30 in the future?

```
date('format string', time()+90);
```

In the above, 90 can be any positive or negative offset.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
date("F d Y H:i:s",time()-90)
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, dates and times are generally worked with as timestamps ; which are a number of seconds since 1970 or so.

To get the current timestamp, you can use `time()`

And to format it, you use `date()`, as you already know.

So, for current time plus 1 min and 30 seconds (ie, 90 seconds) :

```
date('F d Y H:i:s', time() + 90);
```

Or, as an alternate way (a bit more fun ? ), you can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) :

```
echo date('F d Y H:i:s', strtotime('+1 minute +30 seconds'));
```

OK, more complex in this case, I admit ^^

But, in some other situations, it's good to know it exists ;-)